# What is `MultiProfile = multiple` in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf?

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth

I ham troubleshooting some Bluetooth issues and spotted this
in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

```
# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
MultiProfile = multiple
```

What is that? I found some references to multiple profiles in the Bluetooth spec but I am not sure what this exactly does.

The only place I found it at is the source: https://git.merproject.org/mer-core/bluez/commit/e9f873b1c1e2f102ee5353a06e7fede161304c7d 
which didn't help me much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiProfile = x` effectively declares if and what degree of MPS support your device will support.  The comments in your quote say it all.

From the specification:

> The Multi-Profile Specification (MPS) specifies the behavior for
>   Bluetooth devices supporting multiple Bluetooth profiles.
>
> Any device claiming support for this profile shall fulfill all
>   applicable requirements defined in this specification in addition to
>   the requirements defined in each individual Bluetooth profile it
>   supports.

See the link corresponding with MPS (Multi-Profile Service) [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview) for more details of what MPS is.